# How can i install mysql again as i installed workbench mistakenlt once?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed mysql workbench mistakenly. but now i can't install mysql community server. Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: See if you can uninstall Workbench from the Control Panel.  Ideally, this should remove all traces of it, and then you can install the community version.

Comment: This is likely not the problem. Workbench can be installed either before or after MySQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that MySQL Workbench's installation really prevents you from installing a MySQL server. There must be a different problem. Use the [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), which gives you everything you need related to MySQL. It should also recognize the installed WB and offer you updates, if there are any.

Answer (score -1):

It is   better to  uninstall  workbench and  then setup community server.
If  you are doing  this in windows